# sql server 2005 similar to split

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2005, split

I have this table

```
ope_autoventaid                         ope_name
1532ED72-A93C-4287-9EB9-D21AB936F62F    latitud:21.06906|longitud:-89.63837|timegps:2013-08-13 01:07:27
A9B74530-4058-40D8-8AE4-6C1E8ABB4F65    latitud:21.06907|longitud:-89.63825|timegps:2013-08-13 01:08:33
AC0F60D8-5CC6-4ED1-9DED-6C25E5F15031    latitud:21.069|longitud:-89.6383|timegps:2013-08-13 01:12:52
```

How can I get the `latitud`, `longitud` and `timegps`? Sometimes they could be in 0 and timegps in 1900-01-01 but they could not be empty.

On the production server I CAN NOT create a stored procedure, function, view, or create columns/tables, I can only run queries.

Is there a way for get something as it

```
select ope_autoventaid, latitud, longitud, timegps 
from mytable
```

Comment: It would if those were different columns

Comment: Asked and answered multiple times. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+split+string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot create any stored procedures, etc. then there is very little to do except using the SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX functions. The query below is fragile but will produce what you are looking for.

```
SELECT ope_autoventaid,
SUBSTRING(ope_name, charindex('latitud:',ope_name)+8,
                    charindex('|longitud:',ope_name)-9)
    as latitud,
SUBSTRING(ope_name, charindex('longitud:',ope_name)+9,
                    charindex('|timegps:',ope_name)-9-charindex('longitud:',ope_name))
    as longitud,
SUBSTRING(ope_name, charindex('timegps:',ope_name)+8
                  , len(ope_name)-charindex('timegps:',ope_name))
    as timegps
FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.ope_autoventaid,
    x.c.value('r[1]/@lat', 'float') latitud,
    x.c.value('r[1]/@long', 'float') longitud,
    x.c.value('r[1]/@tgps', 'datetime') timegps 
from [Table] t
    cross apply (
        select c=cast(replace(replace(replace(ope_name,
            'latitud:', '<r lat="'),
            '|longitud:', '" long="'),
            '|timegps:', '" tgps="') + '" />' as xml)) x
```